# PHP xPath query sub div elements?

Tags: php, xpath

I have a piece of HTML code that contains sub divs that have information I need to extract. I'm able to query for the parent div or specifically one of the child divs, but I can't seem to do it all at the same time.

For every instance of the `<div class="box"> ... </div>`

1. I need to extract the text from the second  element ("test text" in this case)
2. I need to extract the text from the `<div class="pBox">` ($230 in this case)

Note: the div id "adx_113_x_shorttext" is generally random for each instance but starts with "adx_".

Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <div id="adx_113_x_shorttext" class="shorttext">test text</div>
  <div class="btnLst"><span id="vs_table_IRZ_x_MI52_x_c010_MI52" class="info">
     <flag class="tooltip-show-condition"></flag></span></div>
  <div class="pBox">
    <div>$230</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following PHP code but `$acc_count` isn't aligning well and I'm fairly certain this is not very efficient or the correct way:

```
$acc_count = 0;
$accessories = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'shorttext')]");
$price = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'pBox')]");
foreach ($accessories as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue . " | " . $price[$acc_count]->nodeValue; . "\n";
  $acc_count++;
}
```

Can someone show me the correct way to query the div box class and it's sub divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should get you there:

```
$accessories = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'shorttext')]/text()");
$price = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'pBox')]/div/text()");
$acc_count = 0;
foreach ($accessories as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue  . " | " . $price[$acc_count]->nodeValue . "\n";
  $acc_count++;
};
```